# How to create physical and virtual page?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am trying to create a physical and virtual page using some example.
I am trying to understand how the physical page address is determined.
I have a few questions here.

1. How do we know where the page Info is stored?
   I am guessing that if we divide the virtual address by `PAGE_SIZE` we will get the page number.
   i.e  `val = ((size_t)*virtAddr)/PAGE_SIZE;`
   but I don't understand why do we multiply by 8?
2. When I do `cat /proc/self/pagemap` it just hangs there.
   It seems like it is blocking call. How is my application able to come out from this when it gets the file descriptor?
3. Why do we multiply `PAGE_SIZE * pageInfo` to get the physical address?
   How does that relationship come up? What is the scene behind it?

Here is my code.

```
#include <sys/mman.h> //for mmap and mlock 
#include <unistd.h> //for NULL, lseek
#include <stdlib.h> //for exit and for valloc
#include <stdio.h> //for printf
#include <fcntl.h> //for file opening
#include <stdint.h> //for uint32_t
#include <string.h> //for memset

#define PAGE_SIZE 4096 //mmap maps pages of memory, so we must give it multiples of this size

void makeVirtPhysPage(void **virtAddr, void **physAddr)
{
 *virtAddr = valloc(PAGE_SIZE); // allocate one page of RAM
 
  //force page into RAM
 ((int *)*virtAddr)[0] = 1; 
  //lock it there.
  mlock(*virtAddr, PAGE_SIZE);
  memset(*virtAddr, 0, PAGE_SIZE); // zero-fill the page for convenience 

  uint64_t pageInfo;
  size_t val;
  int file = open("/proc/self/pagemap", 'r');
  printf("The virtAddr is %lu\r\n", *virtAddr);
  printf("The Page size is %lu\r\n", PAGE_SIZE);
  val = ((size_t)*virtAddr)/PAGE_SIZE; // probably getting page number.
  val = val * 8;
  printf("The val is %lu\r\n", val);
  lseek(file, val, SEEK_SET);
  read(file, &pageInfo,8);
  printf("The pageInfo says %p\r\n", pageInfo);
  *physAddr = (void*)(size_t)(pageInfo*PAGE_SIZE); // why multiply by page size?
  printf("makeVirtualPhysPage virtual to phys: %p -> %p\r\n", *virtAddr, *physAddr);
}

void freeVirtPhysPage(void *virtAddr)
{
  munlock(virtAddr, PAGE_SIZE);
  free(virtAddr);
}

int main()
{
  void *virtSrcPage, *PhysSrcPage;
  makeVirtPhysPage(&virtSrcPage, &PhysSrcPage);
  char *srcPage = (char *)virtSrcPage;
  srcPage[0] = 'S';
  srcPage[1] = 'U';
  srcPage[1] = 'P';
  srcPage[1] = 'E';
  srcPage[1] = 'R';

  freeVirtPhysPage(virtSrcPage);
  printf("The value of virtSrcPage[0] is %c\r\n", srcPage[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I don't understand why do we multiply by 8". Isn't it your code? :-) The multiply by 8 is because it is used to read from `procmap` which has 64 bits of info per page.

Comment: It's not my code. Could you elaborate on how the pages and page information structure is and where/how  are they stored?

Comment: [man proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Read the `pagemap` section.

Comment: Is virtual address space is like in the global space? Now, we are dividing it by PAGE_SIZE to get to the page number? Is this correct? If yes, then we multiply by 8 why multiply by 8 rather than Page Frame number  + 8 to reach to the page info.

Comment: Page 0 info is in bytes 0-7 of `pagemap`. Page 1 info is in bytes 8-15. Page 2 info is in bytes 16-23. etc. So the formula is `page_num*8` to get the start address of each `pagemap` info.

Comment: Finally, what is *physAddr = (void*)(size_t)(pageInfo*PAGE_SIZE); ?

Comment: The man page tells you that bits 0-54 are the page frame number. So multiplying by `PAGE_SIZE` will get the physical address (and chop off the original top bits which contains other data).